# JRE 7 JVM updates and optimizations

Tags: java, optimization, jvm

Do we know how frequently does Oracle do things under the hood, e.g. like JVM performance optimizations which *don't* end up in official Java update release notes?

If they don't mention every nook and cranny changed in the JVM for each Update, where would one find such an exhaustive list?

I was just wondering about that since there I am trying to justify upgrading from Java 7 Update 7 to the latest Update and the rest of the programming team is vary of the upgrade (we're running a single-user desktop app with this JRE so I don't think the security fixes are overly important for us).

EDIT: Since old http://bugs.sun.com is down for quite some time, I'd ventured into searching for something similar and have just stumbled upon what seems to be the exhaustive issue list when it comes to JDK - it's hosted on OpenJDK Jira; for future reference, here is the link to JDK 7:
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK#selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.project%3Achangelog-panel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience from switching an application from 1.5, 1.6 to 1.7 over the years you can find most of it in the [Update Release Notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdk7-relnotes-418459.html) however its not always clear what input some changes have to performance or heap space. I notice a increased heap space in some Java 1.6 updates without any changes to our software or any hint in the release notes. But overall I recommend to update to the newest versions, because not only security issues are fixed but also there are sometimes improvements to the garbage collection and you do not fight against strange old bugs which are already fixed by oracle.

But in the end its always a good idea to do some performance tests by your own when updating Java if the performance or heap space is important for the users of the application.

Update:

Some releases have a complete list of bug fixes done. For example [Release Notes Java 7 Update 6](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u6-relnotes-1729681.html) has a link [JDK 7u6 Bug Fixes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/2col/7u6-bugfixes-1733378.html). The bug database of Java can be found at [this](http://bugs.sun.com/) but its not very search or user friendly.

Comment: Understood - so that would mean that there could be some changes to JRE that wouldn't be mentioned in the update notes (such as small-scale improvements to JVM, for example)? Where could one find an exhaustive list for *any* and *all* changes between releases? Is there a public issue tracker?

Comment: Added a update where you can find some more infos about tickets made. But you are always forced to the release notes when they did not mention anything or forget it you will not know.

Comment: Unbelievable - to see such dowdyness and sloppyness in releasing an enterprise piece of software from multi-billion dollar company. I can scarcely believe they have a bug database that's parsecs away from transparency of JIRA, Bugzilla or....pretty much anything else out there. Thanks for your update - I'll sniff around some more; if you do manage to find additional info on this, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The [release notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u-relnotes-515228.html) for each update each have a list of issues that are fixed and enhancements added in each update release.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that, but unfortunately, that is not sufficient. Perhaps I should've mentioned that in the original post. Thank you anyway.